# Scrape a menu and its Google analytics event tracking with BeautifoulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to **scrape** the "burger menu" of one of my website (http://www.lagazettedescommunes.com/) with BeautifulSoup to have the name of each element and its Google event tracking label

So far i have succeed extract all of the 'li' of the menu with BeautifoulSoup but i don't understand how i can have a two list : one with all the label (in the same order than in the menu) and one with all the Google event tracking label

My code so far :

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time
import re


url_gaz="http://www.lagazettedescommunes.com/"
page=urlopen(url_gaz)

soup=BeautifulSoup(page)

nav=soup.findAll('li', class_=re.compile("(itemMenu)"))

for li in nav:
    print(li.contents)

os.system("pause")
```

Do you have idea on how i can get what i want ? (the goal with my two list is after this crawl to call the Google Analytics API to know how many click i have on each elements from this menu)

Thanks a lot for you help and your time

Comment: If it is `your website` why not add an rest API to get that information instead of implementing a crawler?

Comment: Becasue i'm not the lead dev on it (just a webmarketer) and can't do this ;)